Obtaining Research Experience as a Post Baccalaureate
I graduated nearly 5 years ago with a BBA in MIS. Since then, I have been working in unrelated fields from my planned field of study. I recently decided to pursue a graduate degree in statistics and I am currently working on my pre-requisites and studying for the GRE.
A friend, recommended me that I apply as a research assistant at the prestigious program he just finished/graduated from, he recommended that I obtain research experience before applying to increase my chances of being placed.
For someone in my position, how can I go ahead and obtain research experience or relevant experience related my planned field of study?

What country/countries do you plan to study in? How much math do you have?

In the USA, there are so called "post baccalaureate" opportunities at the national labs. But they are not that widespread. Check out, for instance, Zintellect for USA government opportunities (national labs and military labs): https://www.zintellect.com/. If you're somewhere in the world, then I know EU has a nice site with governmental scholarships. Else, I am using this aggregator of worldwide scholarships: https://scholarshipdb.net/. Also, check out "glassdoor" and "indeed" websites. I remember I saw postbacc offerings somewhere, but I don't remember where exactly.

@Buffy I plan on studying in the US. Fortunately, I live here and have citizenship so that is not an issue. As for math, I only just starting Calc 2 and linear algebra.

Research administrator at an R1 here.  I help get people onto payroll.  My school has a postbac program in certain areas (not all).  There are rules, timelines to apply, etc.  I would just google for "postbac program" and the field of study you are interested in to see what is out there.  Here's a quick example that I found for Yale:  https://chem.yale.edu/academics/chemistry-post-baccalaureate-research-education-program
The old-fashioned networking way is to find a PI who will just hire you as a research assistant without a formal program.  We do that all the time as well.  The pay is less than the PhD students receive and also above minimum wage.  At my organization, this is actually the preferred way for faculty, because they can put these sorts of people on grants more easily.  Postbac programs may have requirements that make this more difficult -- all of these rules will depend on the organizations you are working with.  If you can get a recommendation to work with one of your PI's colleagues, that may be a good choice.
While it's been some years since you did your degree, if you were a good worker and productive, the PI may still give you a recommendation.  My PIs take on folks with unusual backgrounds when they know they will be a net positive (hard worker, contributes to the lab work).  If you will need a lot of oversight, you may be a harder sell. It depends on your background.  We have hired folks from industry who have a great work ethic, and they even end up with permanent staff jobs in the lab.  You won't know unless you ask.  If you don't want to ask, you will have to go through a formal program and be subject to those requirements (which may in fact be more work).
